# Can I post same question again?

Tags: support

After I posted a math question, if I did not receive the answer that I expected, can I post the question again?

I think if I modify original question more concrete, I can expect better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting the same/similar question again is discouraged. If you post the same question again, almost surely, it will be closed as a duplicate of your original question.

Here are couple of suggestions, if you want your question to garner attention (or) get better answers.

$1$. You can edit the initial question and add more details. Also, editing the question bounces your question to the first page.

$2$. [You can set a bounty for the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Questions with bounty associated will also be listed on the [featured tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured).

Answer (score 0):

Go over your question, answers and comments. See where the answers diverge from what you are looking for. Perhaps your question wasn't clear enough? Was there some background missing? Need to split it up into several questions, need to make the question more precise? Anything in the coments/answers that should be included?

It might very well be that you get no answers because nobody here knows, or the problem is just too complicated to tackle (and not otherwise attracting). Giving some motivation, explaining where it comes from, might help here.

After doing so, edit your question (as Marvis suggests) or (if split or too heavily reworked) ask another question, perhaps mentioning the original.